# Swift programming - dictionary iterating

Tags: swift, nsdictionary

I am currently reading the swift book provided by apple and want to know how to find out what kind of number is the largest in the following code... I have already found out what is the largest number now I need to "Add another variable to keep track of which kind of number was the largest, as well as what that largest number was."

```
 let interestingNumbers = [
        "Prime": [2,3,5,7,11,13],
        "Fibonacci": [1,1,2,3,5,8],
        "Square": [1,4,9,16,25]
 ]
 var largest = 0
 for (kinds, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
      for number in numbers {
          if number > largest {
              largest = number
          }
      }
  }
  largest
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
let interestingNumbers = [
  "Prime": [2,3,5,7,11,13],
  "Fibonacci": [1,1,2,3,5,8],
  "Square": [1,4,9,16,25]
]
var largest = 0
var kind = ""
for (kinds, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
  for number in numbers {
    if number > largest {
      largest = number
      kind = kinds
    }
  }
}
```

One additional note: If the biggest number appears more than once (if you extend your example to 144 which is a fibonacci as well as 12**2) you would tell only one of both was the biggest. Though both categories have that highest number. Think of a way to return the result as an array. :-)

```
let interestingNumbers = [
  "Prime": [2,3,5,7,11,13],
  "Fibonacci": [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144],
  "Square": [1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100,121,144]
]
```

Comment: Thank you! It's not for a class it's just for my knowledge. I appreciate it

Comment: I guess you could have figured out yourself with a little effort ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted a functional implementation, it might look like:

```
let interestingNumbers = [
    "Prime": [2,3,5,7,11,13],
    "Fibonacci": [1,1,2,3,5,8],
    "Square": [1,4,9,16,25]
]

let result = map(interestingNumbers) { ($0, maxElement($1)) }
    .sorted { $0.1 < $1.1 }.last
```

- The `map` gets an array of tuples consisting of the name of the sequence and the max element in that sequence;
- The `sorted` obviously sorts those results based upon the second element in the tuple; and
- The `last` grabs the last one, i.e. the sequence with the largest max number.

Or, you could use `reduce` to find the tuple with the largest value as its second item:

```
let maxElements = map(interestingNumbers) { ($0, maxElement($1)) }
let result = maxElements.reduce(maxElements.first!) { $0.1 > $1.1 ? $0 : $1 }
```

Comment: Nice solution. But one should note that a `sort` can get slow if the array is lengthy and a direct search runs just once. But from a "dense" perspective this is unbeatable :-)

Comment: Yeah, that's why I added the `reduce` approach, which is O(n), but even that isn't efficient as direct approach.